# Adding content created by custom module to drupal search index

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have developed a module to create content for my site without using CCK. The data will be saved in different tables other than the default tables of Drupal. My requirement is, how can i make Drupal to index the content created by my custom module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to implement [hook_search](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_search/6) in your module that indexes your custom content.

Comment: Hi, after doing some research i found http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_update_index/6 which will be better in the both? In my requirement the regular search should work on my custom content also.

Comment: If you want to use core search then just indexing your nodes could indeed suffice. hook_search will allow you to search your custom content in any way you see fit (using a separate tab on the search page). The 3 basic strategies you could use are listed on [Search interface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/group/search/6) btw.