# Drupal, searching dynamically created pages

Tags: php, drupal, indexing, dynamic-data

My drupal site contains a page where product details are generated from the database based on product id.  One requirement is that product details be searchable.  The Drupal search indexes the static pages.  How can I index the details generated in the dynamic pages.

edit1: I am using php filter to generate the page.  Ex drupalurl/products/id1, drupalurl/products/id2, drupalurl/products/id3 all will pull different content from the db.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding content created by custom module to drupal search index.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816851/adding-content-created-by-custom-module-to-drupal-search-index)

Comment: Refer to the Drupal [Search Interface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/group/search/6) page for more information. You will have to adapt one of the 3 search strategies detailed there to index data from an external source. Implementing [hook_search](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_search/6) in a custom module might be the most relevant solution for your problem.

Comment: Is a "Dynamic page" a page generated by a module, or views? Or is it a page where you (ab)used the PHP-filter to pull stuff in?

Answer (score 1):

[hook_update_index](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_update_index/6) - might be the solution to your problem. You will need to "render" your dynamic fields and send them to the indexer using this hook.